# How to bypass SSL verification with Shrine RemoteUrl plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

I'm using Shrine RemoteUrl plugin in a Rails app to get some file (pdf) from a remote site.
This site have an old https certificate a i'm getting some errors like this:

```
{:media=>["download failed: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: dh key too small"]}
```

I can't  modify the conf of the remote site so i think i need to bypass SSL verification.
But can't find a way to do it.

I'm trying to do this in the Shrine initializer file but i don't know how to pass the right options to Down::Http.
Down::Http backend implements downloads using the http.rb gem (and you can [Disabling Certificate Verification](https://github.com/httprb/http/wiki/HTTPS#disabling-certificate-verification-ie-insecure-usage) with it)

```
Shrine.plugin :remote_url, max_size: 20*1024*1024, downloader: -> (url, max_size:, **options) do
  Down::Http.download(url, max_size: max_size, **options) do |http|
    http.follow(max_hops: 2).timeout(connect: 2, read: 2)
  end
end
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Down::Http.download` forwards all options to http.rb, so you can pass the same `:ssl_context` option:

```
ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ctx.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

Down::Http.download(url, max_size: max_size, ssl_context: ctx, **options) do |http|
  http.follow(max_hops: 2).timeout(connect: 2, read: 2)
end
```

Comment: Thank you but i still got the same error. I don't understand why...
The code works well for another domain but not for my remote site. Will try again tomorow.

Comment: Does not work. SSL is still checked. Don't you think the option should be `http.something` under `http.follow` in the code above?

Comment: When you try using http.rb directly (passing the `:ssl_context` as documented), does that work?